# Can I use Eclipse XQDT to debug Marklogic modules/xquery?

Tags: eclipse, marklogic

Hi Markloggers out there,

I am working now a coupe of months with Marklogic, developping xquery, modules, applications on the ML app server etc etc. I use eclipse a lot, I have XQDT up and running for several marklogic servers. We use the console also.

What I miss is a debug functionality... in Eclispe with XQDT I cannot get the debug function working?

What I need is a nice and clean way to quickly test and develop modelules and functions...
This is my basic lib from the ML example documentation:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

module namespace lib = 'http://www.example.com/lib';

declare function lib:user()
{
xdmp:get-current-user()
};
```

I have this is my XQDT project in eclipse, I have setup a marklogic XDBC server locally and it works ok.

Now I want to use the above module from a file again in the XQDT project in eclipse. But without going to steps of uploading the module to the db etc etc...:

```
(: XQuery main module :)

import module namespace lib = 'http://www.example.com/lib' at 'lib.xq';

lib:user()
```

Gives:

```
XDMP-MODNOTFOUND: (err:XQST0059) Module /lib.xq not found
```

Question 1: Is there a way to find the module without putting it in a module root? In the docs it says from a XQDT project I could source a module but I cannot get it to work...

Question 2: I can execute arbitrary xquery to the local Marklogic server but if I set a debug flag anywhere in a xgy file in the XQDT project and press the debug button I get a popup saying "The Debug Engine is not properly configured". Can anyone explain to me if it is possible to use the debug option in eclipse XQDT with Marklogic 7 ?
Regards,

hugo

Answer (score 0):

It's best to limit yourself to one question per SO post. After all you can only accept one answer.

> Now I want to use the above module from a file again in the XQDT
>   project in eclipse. But without going to steps of uploading the module
>   to the db etc

That's a problem. You can evaluate an ad-hoc query directly. But if it references a library module, that library module needs to be available to the server. You're going to have to copy it to the server sooner or later anyhow, so do it sooner. I don't use an IDE myself, but can't you set it up to do that for you?

> Question 1: Is there a way to find the module without putting it in a module root?

Not in the broadest sense of "module root", no. The docs at https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/import_modules talk about how this works. Somehow or other, you need to make the library module available to MarkLogic.

I can't address your last question. I don't use an IDE, and even if I did I probably wouldn't use a debugger. Instead I `xdmp:log` messages to `ErrorLog.txt`, and occasionally I'll plant an breakpoint-like `error()` call in my code.

Comment: ok, so do you use any other tool then a text editor then? For python dev work I use eclipse a lot and I cannot imagine not using a debugger for that so was thinking those kind of tools would help a lot in developing xquery code...?

Comment: With XQuery variables are immutable by default. That makes it much easier to reason about program flow, because you don't have to worry about functions changing program state behind your back. So I usually don't need anything more than a text editor, `xdmp:log`, and the occasional `fn:error`. It helps to use strong typing and follow other good practices: http://blakeley.com/blogofile/archives/518/ and http://blakeley.com/blogofile/2012/09/28/external-variables-%28code-review,-part-ii%29/ might help.